# Module calling in Pydev plugin in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have Pydev installed in Eclipse and everything works fine. I can import other modules installed through "pip install xxx" without any warnings or errors.

However, I got such a warning when I created two files to test:

test/HelloWorld.py

```
def hello():
    print('Hello World')
```

test/HelloWorldTest.py

```
from HelloWorld import hello

def test():
    hello()
```

I can run this "HelloWorldTest" without problem, which correctly prints "Hello World". However, in my PyDev editor, it always warns that:

```
hello Found at: test.HelloWorldTest

from HelloWorld import hello

―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
Unresolved import: hello
```

Why does it show that 'hello' is unresolved import, which is highlighted in red? However, I can still run it with correct result.

Very strange!

Edited:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your IDE is pointing to a different Python interpreter.

I do not use Eclipse but it happens with PyCharm as well.
In PyCharm I can select a different Python interpreter for the code editor and a different one for running. Normally I would not select different interpreter for the same project and confuse myself but it is possible for edge cases.

I think similar thing is happening with your Eclipse IDE. Please double check your settings and make sure the code editor is pointing to the right Python interpreter.

If you are working on multiple Python projects, it is highly recommended to use some sort of Python Virtual Environment to avoid dependency conflicts. PyEnv (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) is a good one if you are on Linux or Mac.

Im pretty sure the path for the Python interpreter is not set properly on your IDE.

## Answer updated

Why does your folder icons look so different? Are they inside a zip folder or something?

It works perfectly fine on my machine. I do not see any errors.

[image]

Please check my settings.

Window > Preferences > type **python interpreter** in the search box. Try removing the interpreter and manually add again.

[image]

Right click on the project folder > Properties > type **interpreter** in the search box.

[image]

Hopefully this solves your issue.

**Python Virtual Environment**

As you are working on many different projects, it is highly recommended to use a Python Virtual Environment if you haven't already. `PyEnv` (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) is a good one if you are on Linux or Mac. Or you can use the default `VirtualEnv` with `VirtualEnvWrapper` if you are on Windows.

**Quick note on Coding Style**

It has nothing to do with your question but I think its worth mentioning.

I highly recommend you to enable `PEP8` feature on your IDE because it helps you to make your project and code much more consistent.

It is recommended to have module names in lowercase.
ref = https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case, since I have only configured one Python interpreter. And i am not aware Eclipse allows to configure multiple interpreters for editor and the compiler.

Comment: @user697911 Im pretty sure the interpreter path is not set properly on your IDE. Try resetting the Python interpreter from the preferences. Just remove it and manually add again.

Comment: that's correctly set. Otherwise, how can I get correct result when run it in Eclipse by clicking "run as...Python Run"? Something seems fishy.

Comment: @user697911 Could you explain the issue a little bit more please? I will try to replicate it.

Comment: Eddie: please see the snapshot I took. As you can see, 'hello' is not recognized, though it's defined in "HelloWorld.py". However, I can run it fine without problem, despite this warning.